# Char - Java not working as intended / my code

Tags: java

This is my code :

```
char ersterChar = 14;

char zweiterChar = 'B';

System.out.println(ersterChar);
```

When I print out `ersterChar` , it gives me this output : https://gyazo.com/c9d250bb8867ac11ef4f4a944813983c

When I enter `zweiterChar` it does give me the "B" letter.

Am I understanding this wrong?  What I tried doing is lowering the value but I get the same output.

Comment: *Java not working as intended.* Well, what did you intend?

Comment: If you want a printable representation of non-printable character, you can replace them with these in the [Control Pictures](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) block. For example,  `System.out.println((char)(ersterChar + 0x2400))`; add logic as needed. 
You should see  '␎'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only certain characters can actually be printed - this is based on [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  Since 14 comes below the value of printable characters, you're not going to see any meaningful output.

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example of what to insert ?

Comment: The table in the Wikipedia article for "printable characters" is more than sufficient.

Comment: @Roobix13 You still haven't explained what you're trying to do. There's no obvious problem with your code. If it's not doing what you expected, you need to explain what that is.

Comment: I was just trying to do a tutorial on youtube, like nothing should happend just trying to understand basic code.

Answer (score 3):

Java does not use ASCII. Java uses Unicode (UTF-16). Unicode is the superset of ASCII because it the first 128 characters in the Unicode table is the same as in ASCII table. Here is [Unicod table](https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) (note: values in the table are hexadecimal).

First 32 characters in Unicode (also ASCII) are not visible when you print them. These are command characters.
The character 'B' in Unicode has value 66.
If you want to print 'B' then change the value to 66:
`char ersterChar = 66;`

Comment: Perhaps the Java documentation on [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) will help convince.

Comment: Actually, this is orthogonal.  The code points `0x0e` (ASCII) and `0x000e`(Unicode) mean the same thing.  The first 128 Unicode code units are equivalent to ASCII codes, for practical purposes.  The code `14` is the same unprintable character in both ASCII and Unicode.

Comment: @StephenC I updated my answer. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print a "shift out" character, which is outside the range of a normal ASCII characters (between 32 and 128). Anything above that is considered "extended ASCII", and 0 through 31 (and 127) are considered non-printable control characters.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" isn't one thing so it's not really a useful term [because it can be mistakenly interpreted to mean that the ASCII standard has been updated to include more than 128 characters or that the term unambiguously identifies a single encoding, both of which are not the case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

If i may ask, why do you need an integer as a character?
`14` is an integer type not a char. That's why `char zweiterChar = 'B';` works.
`char`is a single character, that is a letter, a digit, a punctuation mark, a tab, a space or something similar. A char literal is a single one character enclosed in single quote marks.
Try redeclaring `char ersterChar = 14;` as `String ersterChar = "14";`

Comment: I was just following a Youtube tutorial, just tying to understand basic code.

Comment: `int` is interchangable with `char`.  That is, you can print out `int`s as you would `char`s, and you can perform arithmetic and increment `char`s at will.    It just so happens that `char` has a *much* smaller amount of values it'll support.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Indeed the JLS allows you to assign an integer *literal* value to a `char` provided that the value of the literal is in the required range.